Common foot note for two authors
The article below has three authors. I need a footnote mentioning that the first two contributed equally, along with a symbol next to the first two authors.
I tried using \thanks but it did not work. What should I do?
\documentclass[twocolumn,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[final,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}


\begin{document}


    \title{Title of the article}





\author{first author$^{1,2,3}$ }
    \email{first.author@gmail.com }

    \author{second author$^{1,2,3}$\footnotemark[1]}
        \email{second.author@gmail.com}
        
        \author{third author$^{1,2,3}$}
        \affiliation{$^1$affiliation1}
        \affiliation{$^2$affiliation2}
        \affiliation{$^3$affiliation3}
        


\maketitle

\end{document}  


welcome! take a look at the samples in the documentation e.g. apssamp.tex which demonstrates how to add footnotes to titles and authors.
